react-native-paper checkbox component returns error
I'm getting a strange error when trying to use a Checkbox component from react-native-paper. I'm not using react-native-vector-icons (using lucide instead), but when I saw this error I tried installing it anyways and rebuilding the app. It's still showing the error. I'm unable to find anything from Google, AI, or Github issues/discussions. The error also doesn't give much in the way of information.
Here is how I'm using the Checkbox:
<Checkbox.Item
  key={preference.id}
  label={preference.preference_label}
  status={preference.preference_value ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'} />

What might be causing this error?


I'm not really understanding where the icon library you are using come into play

I believe it’s used for the actual checkmark in the checkbox

I'm not quite sure why it started working because I'd generated another build before creating this question, but it seems to be working now. I'm pretty sure that by installing react-native-vector-icons, the problem worked itself out. I do know that in the Getting Started docs, it mentions that the library should be installed "because some components use those internally". It'd be great if react-native-paper allowed for more flexibility with customizing icon sets, but at least the issue is fixed!
